# RANK() orders a varchar column incorrectly

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to use RANK() window function to the bottom list of dates:

```
DateId      YearWeek
2006-01-02  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-03  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-04  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-05  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-06  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-07  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-08  Y_2006_W_1
2006-01-09  Y_2006_W_2
2006-01-10  Y_2006_W_2
..          ..
..          ..
```

If I do the following:

```
SELECT DateId, YearWeek, DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order BY YearWeek) as YearWeekId FROM
dbo.Dates
```

Then I will get the following results, which are logically not what I want as "W_10" will get a lower YearWeekId than "W_2" when sorting on that column:

```
DateId      YearWeek    YearWeekId
2006-01-02  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-03  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-04  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-05  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-06  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-07  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-01-08  Y_2006_W_1  1
2006-03-06  Y_2006_W_10 2
2006-03-07  Y_2006_W_10 2
```

How do I write a query to parition on the YearWeek and order by the DateId?

I've also tried

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RowNumber ORDER BY Date) -- Doesn't work either
```

Comment: How is that incorrect? Text sorting is done per character. It doesn't know that those characters are meant to represent numbers and that it should look ahead for other digits and sort intelligently. You should simply not store such data as text, or at least pad the week number to 2 digits so that text sorting will work as you want.

Comment: Make your YearWeek look like `Y_2006_W_01` instead

Comment: No, that's correct, strings aren't numbers, they are strings. `'1'` is **less than** `'2'` and so therefore `'10'` is also less than `'2'` as well; as the first character or `'10'` (`'1'`) is lower than the first character of `'2'`. If you want values to sort like numbers, then don't store then as a string data type.

Comment: @underscore_d It's incorrect because I want Y_2006_W_2 to have YearWeekId = 2. I assumed I could use the DateId to Order by, but this gives incorrect results.

Comment: "It's incorrect because I _want_ ... ." "I _assumed_ ... ." "Would probably learn more code if I wasn't lazy and if I could actually understand and learn how to read my own code...!" (The last from the OP's Profile.) Ralph Waldo Emerson contributes ["A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines."](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored)

Comment: The other option is to just order by `DateId` and it begs the question why you have a separate column for effectively computed data

Comment: @Charlieface For a given week I'd like an easy way to compare to previous weeks using an integer. The table is static, so there's no calculation needed, and the DATEDIFF functions have some 'nuances' when it comes to weeks, leap years, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank is doing just fine.  I would suggest that you change your value to a version that can be ordered, which would zero pad the number:

```
Y_2006_W_01
Y_2006_W_02
. . .
```

In the mean time, this is a very structured string, so you can use string operators to get this right.  Sort first by the length and then by the value:

```
SELECT DateId, YearWeek,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order BY LEN(YearWeek), YearWeek) as YearWeekId
FROM
```

dbo.Dates

Comment: I will update the table and pad the column with a 0